# Custom ProgressWheel of a ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to put like 2 images in the progress Wheel space. One as static background (does not move), and another for the Wheel movement.

For example, I want to show a car moving in circle, while the street stays without moving.

[image: Car moving in a street]

I have my drawable progress_dialog_wheel.XML for the rotating image, which Works excellent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img_car">

    </bitmap>
</rotate>
```

And I use it in the progressDialog:

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.setTitle(title);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_dialog_wheel));
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    return progressDialog;
```

But now I want to add the Street image as "background" of the Wheel. Is there like a `progressDialog.setBackground(...)`? How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: layer-list .... first item road drawable, second rotating_car (same as your have here)

Comment: here where? I dont see link

Comment: by "same as your have here" i meant rotating_car == your current progress_dialog_wheel.XML but img_car should be car only image

Comment: did you mean somthing like this http://selvin.pl/car_on_road.mp4 ? then `layer-list` drawable is the way

Comment: yes, like the last comment. Can you put the answer of How I do it? :)

Comment: **1.** you need 2 images `only_car.png` and `only_road.png` **2.** then you need have `rotating_only_car.xml` drawable with code from you question and `only_car` as bitmap ... **3.** then you need have `progress_rotating_car_on_road.xml` with `layer-list` : **first item** should be `only_road` drawable and **second item** `rotating_only_car` drawable ... **4.** then you can use your new `progress_rotating_car_on_road` as indeterminate drawable of progress bar.

Comment: Excellent, but please solutions must go as answer, not as comment :) else I can't put it as accepted